# Tomcat error: bean's property cant be found

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee, web-applications, javabeans

Tomcat indicates error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /AccueilEmploye.jsp at line 10

7: <body>
8:  <p>
9:  Accueil pour:${masession.type }<br>
10:     Votre id: ${masession.idemp }<br>
11:     Bienvenu<br>
12:     ${message}<br>
13:     email: ${masession.email }<br>
```

This is the AccueilEmploye.jsp file.

```
<body>
    <p>
    Accueil pour:${masession.type }<br>
    Votre id: ${masession.idemp }<br> <%-- ERROR HERE --%>
    Bienvenu<br>
    ${message}<br>
    email: ${masession.email }<br>
    Mot de passe: ${masession.mdp}<br>
    Nom: ${masession.nom}<br>
    Prenom: ${masession.prenom }<br>
    Departement:${masession.dept }
    </p>
</body>
```

Can't figure out where's the problem, Error says that the property idemp isnt available in the bean, while it is there.

```
public class Utilisateur {
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private String email;
private String dept;
private String poste;
private String agence;
private String mdp;
//private int id_emp;
private String type;
private Timestamp date_inscr;
private int idemp;
```

This is the part of the servlet that sends the object emp to the View ( JSP )

```
else {

        msg="";
        request.setAttribute("message", msg);
        session.setAttribute("masession", emp);
        if (emp.getType().equals(Employe)){
                VUE="/AccueilEmploye.jsp";
        } else if (emp.getType().equals(Technicien)){
                VUE="/AccueilTechnicien.jsp";
        } else if (emp.getType().equals(TechnicienR)){
                VUE="/AccueilTechnicienR.jsp";
        } else if (emp.getType().equals(Admin)){
                VUE="/AccueilAdmin.jsp";
        }
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: It might be naming convention problem. check please if idemp has getIdemp() and setIdemp()

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt That's true sir, i solved the problem by changing the setter and getter names from setId getId to setIdemp getIdemp, Solved.
Thank you for the assistance comrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be in the getter of the attribute you're trying to access. The newest jsp `${...}` syntax accesses the attribute throught it's getter.
So, if you want to access attribute `idemp` in jsp using `${masession.idemp}`, you need to have a getter named `getIdemp()` in the respectful class.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw it's already answered...you're lucky you solved it this fast, I struggled for a week until I realized this on my own.

Comment: @TheNorth: if this solution worked for you, please consider clicking the tick mark adjacent, so that it turns green. This is how we mark questions as solved here.